# Card.io move status bar buttons

Tags: ios, card.io

I am using Card.io for iOS and I would like to remove the buttons from the status bar and add those below (cf screenshot) :

First question:

Is it possible? How should I proceed?

I haven't found any possibilities using the CardIoPaymentViewController.

```
 CardIOPaymentViewController *scanViewController = [[CardIOPaymentViewController alloc] initWithPaymentDelegate:self];
 scanViewController.appToken = [GlobalHelper getCardToken];
```

Second and last question:

If I override the CardIOView, may I apply to my fields the Luhn validation (for example) that is used by the CardIOPaymentViewController ?

Answer (score 0):

Dave from card.io here.

[BTW, I don't see your referenced screenshot.]

Sorry -- at the moment there's no way to customize the buttons presented by the `CardIOPaymentViewController`.

And there's not a way for you to access our field-validation code if you switch to a `CardIOView`.

However, it won't be very hard for you to implement your own field validation. Luhn, for example, is well documented.

Comment: Example Luhn validation: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Luhn_test_of_credit_card_numbers#Objective-C

Comment: up vote
0
down vote
accept
Thank you for the clarification. I will implement this feature myself.

Kind regards,